How to write strict generic tuple arrays?
My generic type gets turned into a union. But I want the T to be generic individually for each tuple in the array:
type MyTuple<T extends object> = [T, (s: NoInfer<T>) => any]

const func = <T extends object>(arr: Array<MyTuple<T>>) => {
  // ...
}

func([
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo], // ok
  [{ foo2: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo2], // ok
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo2], // should fail, but doesn't
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo3], // should fail
])

Is there a way to do this?

You can do it like this:
type MyTuple<T> = [T, (arg: T) => any];

function func<T extends any[]>(args: { [K in keyof T]: MyTuple<T[K]> }) {
  // Implementation here
}

func([
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo], // ok
  [{ foo2: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo2], // ok
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo2], // Error
  [{ foo: 'bar' }, (s) => s.foo3], // Error
])


thank you, thank you, thank you! I was searching the web for hours and trying so many things... still unable to solve it. I really appreciate your help!
